# Can a point of inflection be on an indifferentiable point?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Example: if f(c) is defined but not f'(c), can there ever be a point of inflection on f(c)?

Context: I'm a student taking AP Calculus A/B.

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: This depends on your precise definition of inflection point, i.e. if it assumes that the function is twice differentiable at that point or not. If you just mean can a function change convexity at $c$ without being differentiable at $c$, sure it is possible. Take $f(x)=x^2$ for $x<=0$ and $f(x)=\log{x}$ for $x>0$.

Comment: Sry, a bit clearer if you take $\log{(1+x)}$ instead of $\log{x}$.

Comment: The definition of "inflection point" varies among different textbooks. I posted a number of examples in several posts in Math Forum groups over 10 years ago, but unfortunately all their discussion group posts have been removed from the internet. However, an excerpt of what I posted in 2005 is given in [this 14 January 2010 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/Cx56zC9lTAw/m/AfxyC4Tmf0YJ). That said, all the definitions I know assume differentiability (both finite and 2-sided) at an inflection point.